# Finding a stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

How can we find a particular stored procedure. I need to find a stored procedure which I don't know is in which database. Can somebody please, help with a script.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which database server?  With MS SQL Server, you can use [sp_help 'procname'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933429(SQL.80).aspx).

Comment: If the question lacks context about which language, platform or database it is, 99% of the time they mean C#, .net and sql-server. It seems to be an endemic set of virtual blinkers.

Answer (score 1):

One way by using the ANSI information_schema.routines view, change ProcNameHere to the name you want

```
select * from information_schema.routines
where routine_type = 'PROCEDURE'
and specific_name = 'ProcNameHere'
```

Comment: that  is the right way to find the procedurs in DB you can find in it's contains tooo for routine_definition

Answer (score 0):

If it is Sql Server 2005 you can use

SELECT * FROM Sys.Objects where Name = 'YOUR_NAME_HERE' AND type = 'P'

It will tell you if the procedure is in a particular database.

Answer (score 0):

Which SQL? SQL 2k/2k5/2k8 has management studio which lets you browse. Expand Databases/Database/Programmability/Stored Proceudres

Answer (score 0):

Replace *text to search for* with your string and this will search all databases on your server.

```
exec sp_MSforeachdb 'SELECT db=''?'', [type], [name], [text] FROM [?]..sysobjects a inner join [?]..syscomments b on a.id = b.id where text like ''%Text to search for%'' order by [name], [number]', '?'
```